# Catching all click events in one handler with Microsoft Access

Tags: ms-access, office-2007

I am making an on-screen custom keyboard, and I am wondering how to send all click events to one method and have it determine what to do based on the name of the control. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the On Click line to the name of a function, say =MyFunction()

[image: Function on click]

Then:

```
Function MyFunction()
    'The button that was clicked
    Debug.Print Screen.ActiveControl.Name
End Function
```